# During sharepoint migration of sharepoint 2007 to sharepoint 2010 i am getting the following error

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I am migrating the sharepoint site 2007 in to sharepoint 2010. But i am getting the following error.

[STSADM] [V2VFeatureActivation2UpgradeSiteAction (13.0.5.0)] [INFO] [10/3/2012 10:44:29 PM]: SPSite Url=http://etc-share:13202
[STSADM] [V2VFeatureActivation2UpgradeSiteAction (13.0.5.0)] [ERROR] [10/3/2012 10:44:29 PM]: ERROR - Failed to run V2VFeatureActivation2UpgradeSiteAction.Upgrade for SPWeb (http://etc-share:13202) in SPSite (http://etc-share:13202) , the following error occured: Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation. at:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurableObject.CheckPermissions(SPBasePermissions permissionMask)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.ValidateSecurityOnOperation(SPOperationCode code, SPSecurableObject obj)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.AddRowToFeaturesTable(SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, SPSite site, SPWeb web, Boolean fForce)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.Activate(SPSite siteParent, SPWeb webParent, SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, Boolean fForce)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.AddInternal(SPFeatureDefinition featdef, Version version, SPFeaturePropertyCollection properties, Boolean force, Boolean fMarkOnly)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.AddInternalWithName(Guid featureId, String featureName, Version version, SPFeaturePropertyCollection properties, Boolean force, Boolean fMarkOnly, SPFeatureDefinitionScope featdefScope)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.Add(Guid featureId)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Upgrade.SiteAction.ActivateFeature(SPFeatureCollection features, Guid featureGuid, String featureScope, Boolean force)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Upgrade.SiteAction.ActivateFeatures(SPFeatureCollection features, Guid[] featureGuids, String featureScope)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.DLC.Upgrade.V2VFeatureActivation2UpgradeSiteAction.UpgradeWeb(SPWeb web)
[STSADM] [DlcSiteSequence] [INFO] [10/3/2012 10:44:30 PM]: SPSite Url=http://etc-share:13202
[STSADM] [DlcSiteSequence] [ERROR] [10/3/2012 10:44:30 PM]: Action 13.0.5.0 of Microsoft.Office.Server.DLC.Upgrade.DlcSiteSequence failed.
[STSADM] [DlcSiteSequence] [INFO] [10/3/2012 10:44:30 PM]: SPSite Url=http://etc-share:13202
[STSADM] [DlcSiteSequence] [ERROR] [10/3/2012 10:44:30 PM]: Exception: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
[STSADM] [DlcSiteSequence] [INFO] [10/3/2012 10:44:30 PM]: SPSite Url=http://etc-share:13202
[STSADM] [DlcSiteSequence] [ERROR] [10/3/2012 10:44:30 PM]:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.OpenWeb(String bstrUrl, String& pbstrServerRelativeUrl, String& pbstrTitle, String& pbstrDescription, String& pbstrTitleResourceId, String& pbstrDescriptionResourceId, Guid& pguidID, String& pbstrRequestAccessEmail, UInt32& pwebVersion, Guid& pguidScopeId, UInt32& pnAuthorID, UInt32& pnLanguage, UInt32& pnLocale, UInt16& pnTimeZone, Boolean& bTime24, Int16& pnCollation, UInt32& pnCollationLCID, Int16& pnCalendarType, Int16& pnAdjustHijriDays, Int16& pnAltCalendarType, Boolean& pbShowWeeks, Int16& pnFirstWeekOfYear, UInt32& pnFirstDayOfWeek, Int16& pnWorkDays, Int16& pnWorkDayStartHour, Int16& pnWorkDayEndHour, Int16& pnMeetingCount, Int32& plFlags, Boolean& bConnectedToPortal, String& pbstrPortalUrl, String& pbstrPortalName, Int32& plWebTemplateId, Int16& pnProvisionConfig, String& pbstrDefaultTheme, String& pbstrDefaultThemeCSSUrl, String& pbstrThemedCssFolderUrl, String& pbstrAlternateCSSUrl, String& pbstrCustomizedCssFileList, String& pbstrCustomJSUrl, String& pbstrAlternateHeaderUrl, String& pbstrMasterUrl, String& pbstrCustomMasterUrl, String& pbstrSiteLogoUrl, String& pbstrSiteLogoDescription, Object& pvarUser, Boolean& pvarIsAuditor, UInt64& ppermMask, Boolean& bUserIsSiteAdmin, Boolean& bHasUniquePerm, Guid& pguidUserInfoListID, Guid& pguidUniqueNavParent, Int32& plSiteFlags, DateTime& pdtLastContentChange, DateTime& pdtLastSecurityChange, String& pbstrWelcomePage, Boolean& pbOverwriteMUICultures, Boolean& pbMUIEnabled, String& pbstrAlternateMUICultures, Int32& puiVersion, Int16& pnClientTag)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.InitWeb()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.get_Title()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.OpenWeb(Guid gWebId, Int32 mondoHint)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.OpenWeb(Guid gWebId)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Upgrade.SiteAction.Upgrade()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPActionSequence.Upgrade()
[STSADM] [SPUpgradeSession] [INFO] [10/3/2012 10:44:30 PM]: SPSite Url=http://etc-share:13202
[STSADM] [SPUpgradeSession] [ERROR] [10/3/2012 10:44:30 PM]: Upgrade [SPSite Url=http://etc-share:13202] failed. Microsoft.Office.Server.DLC.Upgrade.DlcSiteSequence has the ContinueOnFailiure bit set. Moving on to the next object in sequence.
[STSADM] [SPUpgradeSession] [INFO] [10/3/2012 10:44:30 PM]: SPSite Url=http://etc-share:13202
[STSADM] [SPUpgradeSession] [ERROR] [10/3/2012 10:44:30 PM]: Inner Exception: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
[STSADM] [SPUpgradeSession] [INFO] [10/3/2012 10:44:30 PM]: SPSite Url=http://etc-share:13202
[STSADM] [SPUpgradeSession] [ERROR] [10/3/2012 10:44:30 PM]:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.OpenWeb(String bstrUrl, String& pbstrServerRelativeUrl, String& pbstrTitle, String& pbstrDescription, String& pbstrTitleResourceId, String& pbstrDescriptionResourceId, Guid& pguidID, String& pbstrRequestAccessEmail, UInt32& pwebVersion, Guid& pguidScopeId, UInt32& pnAuthorID, UInt32& pnLanguage, UInt32& pnLocale, UInt16& pnTimeZone, Boolean& bTime24, Int16& pnCollation, UInt32& pnCollationLCID, Int16& pnCalendarType, Int16& pnAdjustHijriDays, Int16& pnAltCalendarType, Boolean& pbShowWeeks, Int16& pnFirstWeekOfYear, UInt32& pnFirstDayOfWeek, Int16& pnWorkDays, Int16& pnWorkDayStartHour, Int16& pnWorkDayEndHour, Int16& pnMeetingCount, Int32& plFlags, Boolean& bConnectedToPortal, String& pbstrPortalUrl, String& pbstrPortalName, Int32& plWebTemplateId, Int16& pnProvisionConfig, String& pbstrDefaultTheme, String& pbstrDefaultThemeCSSUrl, String& pbstrThemedCssFolderUrl, String& pbstrAlternateCSSUrl, String& pbstrCustomizedCssFileList, String& pbstrCustomJSUrl, String& pbstrAlternateHeaderUrl, String& pbstrMasterUrl, String& pbstrCustomMasterUrl, String& pbstrSiteLogoUrl, String& pbstrSiteLogoDescription, Object& pvarUser, Boolean& pvarIsAuditor, UInt64& ppermMask, Boolean& bUserIsSiteAdmin, Boolean& bHasUniquePerm, Guid& pguidUserInfoListID, Guid& pguidUniqueNavParent, Int32& plSiteFlags, DateTime& pdtLastContentChange, DateTime& pdtLastSecurityChange, String& pbstrWelcomePage, Boolean& pbOverwriteMUICultures, Boolean& pbMUIEnabled, String& pbstrAlternateMUICultures, Int32& puiVersion, Int16& pnClientTag)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.InitWeb()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.get_Title()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.OpenWeb(Guid gWebId, Int32 mondoHint)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.OpenWeb(Guid gWebId)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Upgrade.SiteAction.Upgrade()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPActionSequence.Upgrade()
[STSADM] [SPUpgradeSession] [INFO] [10/3/2012 10:44:30 PM]: SPSite Url=http://etc-share:13202
[STSADM] [SPUpgradeSession] [ERROR] [10/3/2012 10:44:30 PM]: Exception: Action 13.0.5.0 of Microsoft.Office.Server.DLC.Upgrade.DlcSiteSequence failed.
[STSADM] [SPUpgradeSession] [INFO] [10/3/2012 10:44:30 PM]: SPSite Url=http://etc-share:13202
[STSADM] [SPUpgradeSession] [ERROR] [10/3/2012 10:44:30 PM]:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPActionSequence.Upgrade()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.Upgrade(Object o, Boolean bRecurse)

Please help... its very urgent

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It means the SSP DB didn't upgrade properly.

If you followed directions from link below, then in some areas they are kind of ambiguous:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263299.aspx

The trick seems to be DO NOT use STSADM to add the SSP or content databases--only use powershell.

These were more complete considering the My Site Host stuff:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alimaz/archive/2009/11/08/upgrading-moss-2007-ssp-user-profiles-and-mysite-content-to-sharepoint-server-2010-using-db-attach-method.aspx

Found this post helpful:
http://www.sharepointjoel.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=0cd1a63d%2D183c%2D4fc2%2D8320%2Dba5369008acb&ID=388

and this one:
http://www.sharepointjoel.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=311

My Sites and profiles are now properly upgraded.

**Still got problem ? look at this link:**

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010general/thread/9b54c713-d6ee-4721-a2c0-146082aa45d6

**EDIT**

Or it could be because MetaData feature isn't enabled check this article out

http://deannaschneider.wordpress.com/2010/06/04/sharepoint-2010-enabling-managed-metadata-features/

Hope it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please say what upgrade are you following?

Nevertheless please try out below link if it is similar to your problem

[SP 2007 upgrade issue](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010general/thread/9b54c713-d6ee-4721-a2c0-146082aa45d6)

Comment: I  am Following the below link.http://rajkamal29.blogspot.com/2009/12/migration-sharepoint-2007-to-sharepoint.html